# Unable to see Dashboard of fabric

Tags: android

I have installed the fabric,integrated jar files and API key.I am always on "https://www.fabric.io/onboard" instead of " https://fabric.io/dashboard".Unable to see the crash report.I have used correct email Id.

Please help,Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

you can see the app here

https://fabric.io/home

and please wait some time to get updated .also double check in your app below line is enabled or not

```
Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
```

also check these from the documentation

If you're getting started with Crashlytics for Android,

> Make sure our SDK line is after all other 3rd-party SDKs Force a crash
>   and then relaunch the app. If you're using our
>   Crashlytics.getInstance().crash() method for testing purposes, make
>   sure it's not in the onCreate method of your launch Activity

Comment: Thanks for reply @jithu. I have used the above line as first statement before any 3rd party initialization.How much i have to wait, as it's been 5 hours.Also "https://fabric.io/home" clicking on this link let me go to onborad i.e. "https://fabric.io/onboard".

Comment: also please go through this link  https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/introduction.html

Comment: App is not visible on fabric

Comment: then i think your integration is not done properly,if its done properly app will show there.you have to add the fabric plugin in your android studio then do

Please refer this for more  -- https://docs.fabric.io/android/fabric/integration.html#

Comment: I have integrated Fabric plugin manually, and icon is showing in android studio."https://fabric.io/onboard/pending" link get stuck to step 1.Unable to proceed in step 2.

Comment: try to integrate using IDE Plugin.then it will work.once you are able to add the plugin to your studio,add your app there and wait for sometime ,it will show in the dashboard .

Comment: Whenever i try to download and add plugin from IDE, It says time-out.what to do then?

Comment: Hey,I got the crash details and able to see the app in dashborad.Reason being,fabric added my app after 1 day into dashboard,I got a mail regarding this.

Comment: its redirecting me to summary screen :(

Comment: faceing same issue with react-native...
have tried several times and recieved "successful upload", yet I'm still being redirected to onboard